# Convert .htaccess to nginx rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I'm attempting to convert the following (PHPVibe) .htaccess rule to gninx:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^embed/([^/]*)/$ /embed.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^feed(.*)$ feed.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?rp=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
</ifModule>
```

This is what I have so far:

```
    rewrite ^/embed/([^/]*)/$ /embed.php?id=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/feed(.*)$ /feed.php last;
if (!-f $request_filename){
    set $rule_2 1$rule_2;
}
if (!-d $request_filename){
    set $rule_2 2$rule_2;
}
if ($rule_2 = "21"){
    rewrite ^/(.*)/?$ /index.php?rp=$1 last;
}
```

The above worked for the most part, except for the fact that it is returning 404 on my non mod_rewrite dependent pages.

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting the following code before your other RewriteRules

```
RewriteRule ^moderator - [NC]
```

It should cause the rewrite engine to skip over any URLs that begin with /moderator/

Comment: But that's an .htaccess rule. I was trying to convert the above rules to nginx. It wasn't necessary to include an exclusion criteria in the htaccess rules but it seems necessary for nginx, which is where I need help.

Answer (score 0):

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @index;
}

location /embed/ {
    rewrite ^/embed/([^/]+)/$ /embed.php?id=$1;
}

location /feed {
    rewrite ^ /feed.php;
}

location @index {
    rewrite ^/(.*)/?$ /index.php?rp=$1;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    # fastcgi directives
}
```

Comment: This causes gnix config errors, and it doesn't seem like it addresses the main issue of excluding the "/moderator" directory.

Comment: There was a typo. And it just does not include moderator directory. You did not say what to do with moderator dir

Comment: I just wanted the rewrite rule to explicitly exclude it, since it's returning 404 with the original rules.

By the way, it's still not working. It now causes php code to download. My version has no problem working. I just want to be able to exclude the moderator folder.

Comment: It looks like the error is not exactly about excluding a directory. The whole syntax is bad I guess. Is there any way you can make some tweaks to the version you suggested to make it work, without necessarily excluding "moderator"?

Answer (score 0):

So, after some tweaking, I've finally figured out the proper rewrite directives for nginx. In case anyone is wondering.

```
    rewrite ^/embed/([^/]*)/$ /embed.php?id=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/feed(.*)$ /feed.php last;
if (!-e $request_filename)
    {
        rewrite ^/(.*)/?$ /index.php?rp=$1 last;
    }
```